# Bison/Yacc Operator Precedence infix vs. prefix

Tags: bison, yacc

So I'm aware that using %left or %right can determine associativity and also precedence. Say,

%left '*' '/'

%left '+' '-'

indicates that multiplication and division have more precedence than sum and subtraction.

However, these are normally for infix operators, i.e. num op num. The problem I'm currently facing is that minus can be used as an infix operator and also as a prefix operator, and their precedence is different (prefix has greater precedence than infix). How would I declare it that way using %left if the token identified is essentially the same?

Comment: This is explained with an example in the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Contextual-Precedence.html).

Comment: Your example is actually backwards -- tokens on the first line have *lower* precedence than tokens on later lines...

Comment: @rici Oh, thanks, I didn't see that. I could swear there weren't any explanation in the manual.